# Mysql query in wordpress takes too much time to execute

Tags: php, mysql

I have sql query in my header file so home page only takes too much time.

```
"select 
t1.*,t2.ID,t2.post_title,t2.post_content,t5.name as itemCat,t4.taxonomy as itemType
from 
$wpdb->postmeta as t1
inner join $wpdb->posts as t2 on t2.ID=t1.post_id 
inner join $wpdb->term_relationships as t3 on t3.object_id=t2.ID
inner join $wpdb->term_taxonomy as t4 on t4.term_taxonomy_id=t3.term_taxonomy_id
inner join $wpdb->terms as t5 on t5.term_id=t4.term_id
where t2.post_status='publish' AND t1.meta_key = '_ait-dir-item' and  t1.meta_value 
LIKE '%".$url->cityName."%' group by t2.ID,itemType"
```

Comment: "%anything" cannot use an index. But "anything%" can.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to execute DDL operations in your database, you can go ahead and try creating some Indexes on your table.

If the size of the database is huge and the query is taking a long time in scanning through various records in your database, then Indexes can be useful as they reduce the time taken to scan effectively.

For creating INDEXES, you can explore the following tutorial:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html

For understanding how INDEXES works and what is the efficient way of Indexing, you can go through the below page:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Incase your query is taking time because of some other factors like slow RAM and less memory to run on the server, then you might need to change the priority of Processes running on your server machine.

Hope you find out what is the roadblock here.